# My Shopify App Not Work on Firefox - Blocked by Content Security Policy

Tags: node.js, express, shopify, shopify-app

I have a problem with my Shopify app

my app works great on Chrome but no work on Firefox

When I enter to it from firefox I have this error message
[image]
My app developed by NodeJS and Express

I'm rally need your help guys
Thank you

Comment: is your application SSL certified? or maybe you need to update your browser

Comment: yes I have ssl and i have last update

Comment: the error is just in the redirect I update res.redirect(authLink) to res.end('<script>top.location="authLink"</script>');

Comment: Yaah redirection can also cause this issue

Comment: yep thank you so much for your response

Comment: interesting, mine did the same thing, but switching it still gives the same error. Looks like mine is due to the Content Security Policy not allowing any sort of redirect.